# How to display select box filter at the top of the table and give it own layout in jquery dataTabale

Tags: datatables

[image]

On the image above, filters are appearing on top of the table. Is it possible to achieve this in jQuery dataTable?

Comment: Please clarify, add more information and your code. I don't understand what do you want achieve.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I mean select filter are only show on table header or table footer. But I want these filter outside the table and show on the top of the table .